# Don't remove infoWindow on elsewhere click

Tags: android, google-maps

I use the mapFragment to display a map.

Since I wanted to disable the centering of the marker, when the marker is clicked, I implemented the following click listener:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        }
    });
    if (!event.getLatlgn().equals("")) {
        LatLng eventLocation = event.getLatlgn());
        Marker location = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(eventLocation).title(event.getLocation()));
        location.showInfoWindow();
        LatLng camera = Events.modify4Camera(event.getLatlgn());
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(camera, 15));
    }
}
```

But when the user clicks anywhere else in the map, the info windows dissapears. How an I fix this? I want the info window to be always open.

Also since I implemented my own onMarkerClickListener, the toolbar in the bottom right corner is not displayed anymore... How can I display it on map load?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the [infoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows) when clicking anywhere in the map, you can programmatically show an info window by calling `showInfoWindow()`. Info windows are designed to respond to user touch events. Also, info window can be hiddden by calling `hideInfoWindow()`.

Here's an example how to use `showInfoWindow()` method:

```
static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.81319, 144.96298);
Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(MELBOURNE)
.title("Melbourne"));
melbourne.showInfoWindow();
```

For more details, you may try this demo app. This demo app includes `showInfoWindow()` method: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java